# Vert.x Write Buffer to WriteStream?

Tags: vert.x

At a Vert.x verticle I'm implementing I have a Buffer that was previously loaded into memory and now I want to dump it into disk.

As far as I understood we should use a Pump to make sure not to overload the WriteStream.

But I'm not finding a way to get a ReadStream child instance from a Buffer. Shouldn't there be an easy / standard way to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, vert.x does not warn on any issues writing directly into `AsyncFile`s. Furthermore, they provide the corresponding example of using `AsyncFile.write` directly here and state that you can use those to write directly: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_asynchronous_files

However, if you want the `pump` with `Buffer` you need an instance of `ReadStream<Buffer>` along with an `AsyncFile` to pump into. You can make use of the implementation by PitchPoint Solutions (Copyright 2016 The Simple File Server Authors):

https://github.com/pitchpoint-solutions/sfs/blob/master/sfs-server/src/main/java/org/sfs/io/BufferReadStream.java

Putting it all together:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> done = new CompletableFuture<>();

Buffer buffer = Buffer.buffer(new byte[100]);

Vertx.vertx().fileSystem.open("myfile.txt", new OpenOptions(), res -> {
    if (res.succeeded()) {
        AsyncFile outputFile = res.result();

        BufferReadStream reader = new BufferReadStream(buffer)
        Pump pump = Pump.pump(reader, outputFile);
        pump.start();
        reader.endHandler((r) -> {
            pump.stop(); // not sure this is required
            done.complete(null);
        });

    } else {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
});

// wait elsewhere
done.get();
```